# SKCropNode - Cropped node responding to touch

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, skcropnode

I am trying to make a sort of a scroll view using SKCropNode. The size of the scroll view is set to the mask node and the child nodes are then cropped when they move outside the mask's region. I have put various subclassed SKSpriteNodes, each with their own touch events, on this scroll view. However, they still respond to the touch events even while being cropped out!

Can anyone suggest a way to resolve this?

Comment: You can take a look at this https://github.com/lboban/ScrollNode.
Basic functions work, it includes crop node and has full scrolling capabilities.

Comment: Same problem exists with this as well... The cropped nodes (which are Sprite Kit buttons I created myself) are still detecting touches. Any other solution?

Comment: This is a bug in SKCropNode. I will report it to Apple and update this post with more information as I receive it.